# Discover default GATT services

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

In my iOS application, I am connecting to other BLE devices and discovering their services as such:

```
peripheral.DiscoverServices();
```

But it only discovers the services that I created myself, none of the default GATT services. I want to get the `Generic Access` service (0x1800) so I can read characteristics from it. How can I do this?

Comment: I think it's hidden by the system. Which characteristics are you interested in?

Comment: For now, just the `Device Name` (0x2A00). I know I can get it as soon as I connect to the peripheral, but was hoping for a more systematic approach because I am building a library for reading characteristics.

Comment: @Darius Here is an article for reference.(https://wojciechkulik.pl/xamarin-ios/how-to-communicate-with-bluetooth-low-energy-devices-on-ios)

Comment: I'm actually following that article as reference, my code is as in the article.

Comment: @Emil I guess it is hidden on ios. Because I actually have to call `DiscoverServices()` before I can find the device name in the `peripheral` object. If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These services are hidden by the system. You can get some characteristic values by the API. The name for example can be read by simply reading the name property of the peripheral object.